# Como puedo reemplazar el NULL por una cadena de texto en una consulta en sql

Tags: sql-server

```
SELECT MONTH(pag_fecha) AS Mes, SUM(pag_importe) AS Ingresos
FROM PAGO
GROUP BY MONTH(pag_fecha) WITH ROLLUP
```

Quisiera que en ves de NULL me salga "Ingresos totales"

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ya lo intente con un CASE pero quiero saber si había una manera mas sencilla de hacerlo ya que en el CASE tengo que poner todos los meses para que me muestre el resultado que quiero

```
SELECT CASE MONTH(pag_fecha)
WHEN 1 THEN '1'
WHEN 2 THEN '2'
WHEN 3 THEN '3'
WHEN 4 THEN '4'
WHEN 5 THEN '5'
WHEN 6 THEN '6'
WHEN 7 THEN '7'
WHEN 8 THEN '8'
WHEN 9 THEN '9'
WHEN 10 THEN '10'
WHEN 11 THEN '11'
WHEN 12 THEN '12'
ELSE 'Total General'
END AS Mes,
SUM(pag_importe) AS Ingresos
FROM PAGO
GROUP BY MONTH(pag_fecha) WITH ROLLUP
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una forma más compacta es la siguiente:

```
SELECT ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR,MONTH(pag_fecha)), 'Total General') AS Mes,
       SUM(pag_importe) AS Ingresos
       FROM PAGO
       GROUP BY MONTH(pag_fecha) WITH ROLLUP
```

Es necesario convertir el mes en un `varchar` (`CONVERT(VARCHAR,MONTH(pag_fecha))`) porque en la misma columna vamos a tener un texto para el total general y por último, con `ISNULL(<valor columna>, <valor si es null>)` agregamos el texto `Total General` justamente para esta fila

Answer (score 1):

Esto se podría lograr con un `case` simple , validaríamos cuando *(when)* el campo `pag_fecha`  sea `null` , entonces *(then)* mostramos el texto *"Ingresos totales"*, caso contrario *(else)* mostramos simplemente el mes de la fecha con `MONTH(date)`

**Ejm**

```
SELECT CASE WHEN pag_fecha IS NULL 
        THEN "Ingresos totales" 
        ELSE MONTH(pag_fecha)
        END AS Mes
from PAGO
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a79dfb/4/0)</kbd>